# Delayed initialization of QuartzInitializerListener

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a requirement to create quartz table using java code and then  initialization QuartzInitializerListener servlet ***without restarting the server***. Is there any way possible to achieve it?

Currently when I start my jboss, QuartzInitializerListener is trying to get  initialized but the tables are not present so it throws certain errors:

```
[STDOUT] Quartz Scheduler failed to initialize: org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't clean volatile data: Invalid object name 'QRTZ_TRIGGERS'. [See nested exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'QRTZ_TRIGGERS'.]]
13:32:50,279 ERROR [STDERR] org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't clean volatile data: Invalid object name 'QRTZ_TRIGGERS'. [See nested exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'QRTZ_TRIGGERS'.]]
13:32:50,280 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.initialize(JobStoreSupport.java:582)
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
         <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </context-param>
     <context-param>
         <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </context-param>


     <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener
            </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

**quartz.property**

```
org.quartz.dataSource.arch.jndiURL  = java:/abcDBJndi 
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.JobInitializationPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = jobs.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.overWriteExistingJobs = true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 100
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction = false
```

I realized QuartzInitializerListener can not handle request but if there is any way to set the jndiURL using java code and initially jobs.. Please help!!

Comment: create the tables in the listener code?

Comment: I don't think so I will be able to do that.. It is part of an installation process..